# Sass syntax error: Invalid CSS after

Tags: sass, syntax-error

Sass is giving me syntax error with this:

```
$colors: (pantone3435c: #2d4838, pantone1788c: #e62c3a, white: #ffffff, pantone3434c: #14482f, pantone468c: #e2cba4, pantone571c: #99d1c7, pantone169c: #f5aea8, pantone1345c: #f5aea8, pantone672c: #e29fc7);

@each $name, $color in $colors {
    body.#{$name} {
      background: $color;
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine on sassmeister.com but not on my host where Sass 3.3.3 (Maptastic Maple) is installed.

In order to get it to work I had to rewrite it into:

```
$colors: pantone3435c #2d4838, pantone1788c #e62c3a, white #ffffff, pantone3434c #14482f, pantone468c #e2cba4, pantone571c #99d1c7, pantone169c #f5aea8, pantone1345c #f5aea8, pantone672c #e29fc7;


@each $entry in $colors {
    $name: nth($entry, 1);
    $color: nth($entry, 2);

    body.#{$name} {
      background: $color;
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the first example or is it that my version of Sass doesn't support it?

Comment: I tried your code with my SASS 3.3.3 and it works. Maybe the error is elsewhere?

Comment: No error elsewhere. Sass compiles just fine if I remove the code or replace it with the code in the second example.

Comment: but what's the error reported ?

Comment: Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...: (pantone3435c": expected ")", was ": #2d4838, pant..." on line 1 of path/to/_colors.scss

Comment: Are you sure you're actually using Sass 3.3?  If you're using Compass < 1.0, you'll actually be using Sass 3.2.x

Comment: Hmmm... sass -v says 3.3.3, but yeah Compass is 0.12.2. Is there a stable version of Compass > 1.0?